# Which one is the best COMET server?

Tags: php, jquery, comet

I'm looking for a COMET server, i want to push messages from the server specifically to some users with some id's, i'm using php and i'm looking for a good and easy COMET server.

Could you tell me which one is the best?

Answer (score 4):

This is subjective without more details.  We've looked at APE, Node.js implementations, and others- all offer slightly different strengths / weaknesses.

If you're only interested in the functionality and don't want to develop the competencies or own the responsibilities of managing your own comet server there are fairly mature 'Comet' as a service offerings.  I've used [Pusher](http://pusherapp.com/) on a recent project, it delivered everything we needed and might be a good place to start.

Comment: We used APE about a year ago, and it suffered from a terrible memory leak that could only be contained with running a cron job that restarted the service every day. Other than that, the APE server worked flawlessly, it's open-sourced, so it maybe the case that the memory issue has been fixed by now.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of the comet server depends on the kind of app you are developing. If you have plans of porting your app to mobile platforms in the future , then you can go for [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/). This is simple to use, provides a simple API for you to publish from a javascript client, from PHP, from iOS client and also from a .NET client. Also, you can use Websync either as a server or on-demand. But, the thing is, WebSync's free version allows only upto 10 concurrent clients. If you want more, you will have to purchase.

I have also looked a little bit into [APE](http://www.ape-project.org). This is completely open source and all your code has to be written in Javascript which may be a little inconvenient in some cases. Make your choice depending on your needs

Comment: Good points, also wanted to mention that the Javascript that is needed to open channels on APE also work on iOS Safari and the Android browser

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use APE 
http://www.ape-project.org/

Reasons :
http://www.ape-project.org/ajax-push.html

Comment: Would be nice to hear why you recommend APE over the other alternatives